# Handling "ends with" routes in Slim 3 (beta)

Tags: regex, routes, slim

I'm using Slim Framework 3 (latest beta). The routing rules have been updated, and now extends nikic/FastRoute.

I'm having trouble getting a "ends with" route working right. Below are the two routes I have:

```
$app->get('/{uri:.*(?:css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$}', function (){ [...] });
$app->get('/{uri:.*}', function (){ [...] });
```

Per FastRoute, we can't use regex multi-match blocks (), but they suggested to use backreference blocks to get the same effect: https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute#defining-routes

However, this isn't working.

What I'm trying to do is do a catch-all route, with a different route specifically for webpage assets (images, etc).

Comment: I used `$app->get('/asset/{asset:[a-z]+\.(?:css|js)}', function($req, $res, $args) {` for generated assets, but I think it's no "ends with".

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this pattern successfully to reroute assets in Slim 3:

`'/assets/{file:.+}.{ext:css|js|woff|woff2|ttf}'`